# Angular 7 -Sort select drop down options in custom order

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a select drop down where options are fetched from service dynamically using *ngFor .I want to reorder the options order in my custom way. is it possible to do from angular code.

```
The array is like this
console.log(this.paymentTypeData);
Array(5)
0: {value: "DAILY", code: "D", label: "Daily"}
1: {value: "SINGLE_TIER", code: "ST", label: "Single Tier"}
2: {value: "MULTI_TIER", code: "MT", label: "Multi Tier"}
3: {value: "NO_DISCOUNT", code: "ND", label: "No Discount"}
4: {value: "EOM", code: "EOM", label: "End of Month"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Currently they look in this Order**

Daily
Single Tier

Multi Tier

No Discount

End of Month

**I want to display in the below order**

No Discount

Single Tier

Daily

Multi Tier

End of Month

```
    HTML:
   <select
   class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let list of paymentTypeData" [ngValue]="list.code">
   {{list.label}}
   </option>
   </select>

   Typescript:
    public paymentTypeData: any;
     
     this.supplier.getPayTermTypes().subscribe(paymentTypes => {
     this.paymentTypeData = paymentTypes;
});
```

Comment: Yes. you can use javascript sort function

Comment: In this case javascript sort won't work, we can either sort alphabetically or based on a field, but for your requirement you need to add a sort field in the backend

Comment: @developglobal As I can see you've completely changed your question. You should mention that you are using the Mat table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a pipe for it.

**html:**

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let i of items | myOrder" [value]="i">{{i.title}}</option>
</select>
```

**module:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyOrderPipe
  ]
```

**component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

export interface IItem {
  value: string;
  code: string;
  label: string;
  order?: number;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'myOrder',
  pure: false,
})
export class MyOrderPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: IItem[]): IItem[] {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
      return;
    }
    array = array.sort((a: IItem, b: IItem) => a.order - b.order);
    return array;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: IItem[]; // <-- from server
  items: IItem[]; // <-- new array with the order field

  ngOnInit() {
    const mySettings = {
      1: 'No Discount',
      2: 'Single Tier',
      3: 'Daily',
      4: 'Multi Tier',
      5: 'End of Month',
    };

    this.items = this.data.map((item: IItem) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        order: this.getKeyByValue(mySettings, item.label),
      };
    });
  }

  getKeyByValue(object, value): number {
    return Number(Object.keys(object).find((key) => object[key] === value));
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated my question with code can you provide a solution please

Comment: Hi Dmitry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018803/angular-7-typescript-sort-select-drop-down-options-in-particular-order/65018944?noredirect=1#comment114949025_65018944  can you check this quesion and provide a answer there pelase it is more clear there

Comment: @developglobal Updated my answer. Please check it out

Comment: @developglobal I would recommend adding the order field on the back-end side. But if it is not possible my answer will help you to do on front-end.

Comment: should i create a custom pipe and import in my ts file or can i place this code directly into my ts file

Comment: so i can write your code directly in typescript file

Comment: Hi Dmitry data: IItem[]; // <-- from server
  items: IItem[]; // <-- new array with the order field
you mentioned from server so is there any change in place of IItem or i can keep your exact code as it is.please help sir because when i use your exact code it does not work i used a pipe with your code

Comment: please help me out sir i have project submission

Comment: @developglobal Could you create a sample on codesandbox.io?

Comment: sure i will create

Answer (score 0):

Sure. `*ngFor` uses the order of the array you give it, the easiest approach is sorting the array before passing it on to `*ngFor`.

How this looks in code will depend on how you are currently fetching the data. For instance, if you are doing

```
class WhateverComponent {
  selectOptions$ = this.service.fetchOptions();

  ...
}
```

You would add

```
class WhateverComponent {
  selectOptions$ = this.service.fetchOptions().pipe(
    tap(array => {
      array.sort((x,y) => x.order - y.order)
    })
  );

  ...
}
```

to sort the options by their "order" property,

or if you are doing

```
class WhateverComponent {
  selectOptions: Array<WhateverOption>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.fetchOptions().subscribe(array => {
      this.selectOptions = array;
    })
  }
}
```

you'd change this to

```
class WhateverComponent {
  selectOptions: Array<WhateverOption>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.fetchOptions().subscribe(array => {
      array.sort((x,y) => x.order - y.order);
      this.selectOptions = array;
    })
  }
}
```

Further information on how to use `sort` may be found [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Hi meriton updated my question can you please provide the exact solution with changes in your code please help me out sir . i have project submission