# Angular 7/Typescript -Sort Select drop down options In Particular Order

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `select dropdown` where options are fetched from service dynamically using `*ngFor`. I want to reorder *the order of the option* in my custom way. Is it possible to do from angular code?. The array is like this

```
   console.log(this.paymentTypeData);
Array(5)
0: {value: "DAILY", code: "D", label: "Daily"}
1: {value: "SINGLE_TIER", code: "ST", label: "Single Tier"}
2: {value: "MULTI_TIER", code: "MT", label: "Multi Tier"}
3: {value: "NO_DISCOUNT", code: "ND", label: "No Discount"}
4: {value: "EOM", code: "EOM", label: "End of Month"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Currently they look in this Order**

- Daily
- Single Tier
- Multi Tier
- No Discount
- End of Month

**But I want to display in the below order:**

- No Discount
- Single Tier
- Daily
- Multi Tier
- End of Month

HTML:

```
  <select
   class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let list of paymentTypeData" [ngValue]="list.code">
   {{list.label}}
   </option>
   </select>
```

Typescript:

```
public paymentTypeData: any;
     
     this.supplier.getPayTermTypes().subscribe(paymentTypes => {
     this.paymentTypeData = paymentTypes;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a sortOrder property in your paymentTypes, then when you fetch your paymentTypes you can sort them on that specified order.

```
this.paymentTypeData.sort((a,b) => a.sortOrder > b.sortOder ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: @developglobal any reason in particular? Given your problem statement I can only see it's not any default sorting (name based), therefor I suggested setting a custom property to create a sorting upon.

Comment: Updated my question with array can you provide a correct solution please

Comment: In that list there is no way of making sure you'll always have the correct order, since you have nothing to base that sorting upon. {value: "DAILY", code: "D", label: "Daily", sortOrder: 3} <- adding a sorting option containing the correct values for each object, can allow you to sort it. If you cannot add a sorting order, i don't think it is possible to sort it in this way.

Comment: can you provide a code for this solution pleaseeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Lotte Lemmens solution of adding a sortOrder on the back-end would be ideal rather than adding it in the front-end.

However if you cannot change the back-end you can introduce a lookup table defined in the front-end to determine your sort order.

Define each key in your table to the value of the property you wish to sort by. In this case "value":

```js
const sortOrderTable = {
  "DAILY": 0,
  "SINGLE_TIER": 0,
  "MULTI_TIER": 0,
  "NO_DISCOUNT": 0,
  "EOM": 0
}
```

Now adjust each specific value to reflect your desired sort ordering.

Finally, add a pipe to your request in your `.ts` to perform the sorting:

```js
this.supplier.getPayTermTypes()
  .pipe(
    map(apiResponse => apiResponse.sort((a,b) => sortOrderTable[a.value] > sortOrderTable[b.value] ? -1 : 1)))
  .subscribe(paymentTypes => {this.paymentTypeData=paymentTypes;});
```

**NB** This is brittle design as it relies on the property name of the response object from your server to not change in order to match the property values to the sort order table.

Comment: When i use your exact code it does not work can you please make some code changes