# angular 9 reorder/sort siblings dom by using querylist(contentChildren or ViewChildren)

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular9

I was wondering whether angular let you reorder/sort the sibling DOMs or not.

[image: pic1]

For example, If I want to re-arrange(change the order) the `opt` component. How can I do it?

`my-lib-select` is a select or Dropdown component and `opt` is a child component to generate the options for select.

Component is generated or render in other components like this.

I.e `app.component.ts`

```html
<my-lib-select [customComparator]="customComparatorFn">
  <opt *ngFor="let x of finalCompOptions">{{x}}</opt> 
</my-lib-select>
```

In `my-lib-select`, I have a QueryList

```
  @ContentChildren(OptComponent, {descendants: true, read: OptComponent})
  options: QueryList<OptComponent>;
....
if (this.customComparator) {
   const arr = this.options.toArray();
   arr.sort(this.customComparator);
   this.options.reset(arr);
}
```

But this is not ordering the siblings or sorting.

I know, I can sort the `finalCompOptions` in `app.component.ts` but I would like to sort the options from `my-lib-select`.

Anybody can help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not pass finalCompOptions in my-lib-select anald also render the opts from there..? Sorting the DOM here really is not a good solution (it will clash with Angular)

Comment: yeah, I can do that. But If I want to customize the options content. Say I want to add the images to some options and some others not. And I Know I can use the Ng-template for it but I still want to know if it is possible to change the sibling order or not for security propose.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you've got two ways of tackling this.

Method 1 - You reorder the items within app.component.ts prior to render/passing them through your ngFor.

Method 2 - You reorder using a custom pipe [like seen in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65016723/angular-7-sort-select-drop-down-options-in-custom-order)